# How to say "Any Character" in regular expression?

Tags: regex

I want to search for a line which starts with lets say a and ends with z. In-between any number of any character can come. How can i write an expression for this?
( I dont want to explicity mention any digits, any special chars, any alphabets )
I don't to do something like ^[**0-9,a-z,A-Z,list all special chars**]*$.

Comment: The exact flavor (i.e. implementation language) you're using for the regex will help us give more detailed answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
^a.*z$
```

`.` is the regex metacharacter that matches anything.

`*` is a greedy modifier that repeats the previous item 0 or more times, trying for the biggest number of matches first, followed by smaller permutations until the preceding item cannot be matched at all, which will in fact, still make the overall regex match.

Comment: No, newlines are not matched by `.` in multiline mode (`m` flag), they're matched by `.` in single-line mode (`s` flag). Multi-line mode causes `^` and `$` to match the start and end of any line rather than the start and end of the entire string.

Comment: @Adrian Ah yes! Sorry about that! I did not remember exactly which one was which (`s` & `m`). Thanks for the correction and I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Ok . But this raised me one more question. how to use s or m in an expression?

Comment: @Vijay: This depends on the regex engine. Sometimes you need to compile the regex with a special options, sometimes you add a modifier within the regex, sometimes you add a modifier after the regex delimiter - as Fred Nurk has commented (and as the regex FAQ says) you need to tell us the regex engine you're using.

Comment: @Vijay Javascript's regex engine does not support the `s` flag, just the `m`, `g`, and ` i` flags. You could use a character class like `[\s\S]` which matches both whitespace characters and non-whitespace characters.

Answer (score 4):

```
^a.*z$
```

If you want to change it from "any number (including zero) of characters" to "one or more characters", then change the * to +.